# q-coding in addCustomHeader with List-Unsubscribe link

Tags: phpmailer, list-unsubscribe

I have a problem with PHPMailer and List-Unsubscribe header.
According to the documentation I am trying to add a header for unsubscribing from emails in the mail UI:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe", '<'.$unsubscribe_uri.'>');
```

In general, the unsubscribe link looks like:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe", '<https://example.com/unsubscribe?ddd=asfsfsdf-asdfasfsaafasfsafsfsdfsdfdsfsdf>');
```

but in the incoming letters in the headlines I see:

```
List-Unsubscribe: =?us-ascii?Q?<https://example.com/unsubscribe/=3Fddd=3Dasfsfsdf-asdf?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?asfsaafasfsafsfsdfsdfdsfsdf>?=
```

I understand that PHPMailer strives to comply with RFC 2047, but the largest sites (twitter, facebook, paypal) in their newsletters do not encode unsubscribe links.
Yandex-mail technical support directly replied that it is better to avoid q-coding in The list-Unsubscribe header in emails.
How to be, colleagues?

Comment: I'm aware of this - it will be changed in the next release of PHPMailer.

Comment: @Synchro
Oh, thank you so much! I honestly, after communicating with the support of mail services for a couple of weeks already lost hope and began to think about another package. I look forward to it!

Comment: [Released in PHPMailer 6.1.4](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases/tag/v6.1.4).

Comment: @Synchro Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note about the above fix - the reason it's applied is to work around a bug in PHP's `mail()` function - and the latest versions still do the same thing when using that. The fix is to switch to using SMTP to localhost (call `isSMTP()`), which doesn't suffer from the PHP bug and so doesn't apply the same wrapping and encoding rules.